# allow app store access but no purchases

Tags: ios, ios-appstore, parental-controls, in-app-purchase

My understanding is that iOS parental controls let you (a) disallow in-app purchases, and/or (b) hide the app store altogether.

I am hoping for an option where the child can browse the app store and download ("Get") free apps, but not be able to download/buy apps that cost money.

Am I missing something, or is that not possible? And if not, why doesn't Apple offer that? I want my kid to be able to, say, hear about a new game from their friend, download ("Get") it for free, and play it without me having to be involved. But I don't want them to be able to buy an app or make in-app purchases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use the [Ask to Buy](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT201089) feature provided in Family Sharing. However you have to approve every time your child tries to buy **or download** contents.

Another option is to remove the payment method from the Apple ID. If you share an Apple ID with your child, then it is recommended to create a separate one for your child.

Comment: Thanks, but doesn't every Apple ID need to be tied to a valid credit card?